# Why is a </html> tag inserted at the end of my minimal Seam page?

Tags: ajax, json, jsf, jquery-plugins, seam

I have been searching for an answer to my problem for two days now, so I figure its time to ask. Hopefully someone wiser in the ways of JSF and Seam (it won't take much, I'm still new to both) will be able to enlighten me.

I have a Seam application that requires a dropdown, but one that the user can type into as well. This will allow user-created entries as well as pre-defined ones. I am attempting to create this combobox using the [FlexBox](https://flexbox.codeplex.com/) jQuery plugin. It seems like a good candidate for what I need. I just need to specify a div and a page that returns JSON data in order to create this combobox effect.

*add-codes.html*

```
...
<div>
Department: <div id="dept-dropdown" />
</div>
...
```

*AccountComboBoxList.java*

```
...
@Scope(SESSION)
@Name("actComboBoxAction")
public class AccountComboBoxList implements Serializable {
...
@WebRemote
public JSONObject getDepartmentJSON() {
    JSONObject returnJSON = new JSONObject();
    try {
        //if dept name is null, skip this and return empty obj
        if(deptName!=null) {
            JSONArray returnArray =
                JsonDataHelper.convertAcctToolEnt2JsonArray(deptName);
            returnJSON = new JSONObject();
            returnJSON.put("results",returnArray);
            logger.info("JSON results: "+returnJSON);
        }
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        logger.warn("JSONException thrown!");
        logger.warn(je.getMessage());
        je.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return returnJSON;
    }
}
...
```

*deptString.xhtml* - in its entirety

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">

<h:outputText value="#{actComboBoxAction.getDepartmentJSON()}" />

</ui:composition>
```

Then in my javascript file I simply create the combobox with this line:

```
...
$("#test-string").flexbox('./includes/deptString.seam');
...
```

The problem comes in at this point. deptString.seam calls the seam method correctly and successfully returns a JSONObject. But the combobox doesn't work correctly because a '' is attached on the end of the string.
For example, I copy-and-pasted this from the resulting 'View Source' of the page:

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"Dept1"},{"id":"2","name":"Dept2"},{"id":"3","name":"Dept3"}]}</html>
```

What is adding this extraneous tag and is there *any* way to get rid of it?
I created a text file with just the proper JSON in it and called that file into the .flexbox() method. The combobox worked as advertisted then, so I know the flexbox code works.
I also tried removing all the JSF code from the deptString.xhtml file and had just the single line `#{actComboBoxAction.getDepartmentJSON()}` in the file. This caused a 'com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /includes/deptString.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.' error.

Like I said, i'm new to JSF and Seam. If there is an obvious/better way to get a simple String from the backend to the frontend in a Seam/JSF application, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The Error Parsing /includes/deptString.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.' error. is happening because you still need the ui:composition tag around the expression. Although it probably wont fix your problem

Comment: Not sure about the Seam part, but I can tell that you're basically abusing JSF as being a web MVC framework as a webservice. Consider using a real webservice API, such as JAX-WS or JAX-RS.

Comment: If your javascript was in a facelet (xhtml) file the you should be able to do $("#test-string").flexbox('#{actComboBoxAction.getDepartmentJSON()}'); this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file mentions someways of achieving this

Comment: Hey guys,
Thanks for the answers! I have something that is working now, using your suggestion reevesy!
I appreciate the input BalusC (and also for the answer on the question that reevesy linked to). I can see your point about the JSF framework abuse. I guess I got wrapped up and confused in the Seam Remoting that lets you call Seam methods from javascript (hence the @WebMethod annotation). I'll take a look at the frameworks you mentioned and and see if I can implement one of them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your javascript was in a facelet (xhtml) file the you should be able to do

```
$("#test-string").flexbox('#{actComboBoxAction.getDepartmentJSON()}');
```

[Mixing JSF EL in a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file) mentions someways of achieving this

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  Why is the </html> being included?  Guess I'm being harsh, but whatever.  It solves that particular person's problem, but why is that html tag being stuff in there?