# Getting an EL in a Javascript file, loaded by @ResourceDependency

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, el

I'm using `@ResourceDependency` annotation in a JSF component to add Javascript and CSS files into my JSF page.

In my Javascript file, I need to reference another resource file (a .swf file, which located in META-INF/resources, as JSF requires). I tried to put a `#{resource['swf:file.swf']}` EL expression in my javascript code, but it won't get resolved.

For exapmle, for the following JS file in the server:

```
var instance = new JSClass();
instance.setResourceUrl("#{resource['swf:file.swf']}");
```

The browser gets:

```
var instance = new JSClass();
instance.setResourceUrl("#{resource['swf:file.swf']}");
```

which is wrong.

While when I put the same EL in the CSS file, it get resolved properly. For the following CSS file in the server:

```
.instance-css-class {
  background: url("#{resource['swf:file.swf']}")
}
```

The browser gets:

```
.instance-css-class {
  background: url("/webapp/javax.faces.resource/file.swf.jsf?ln=swf")
}
```

Which is exactly what I need, but in the JS file.

Obviously, I can use the CSS as a workaround for the issue (Create a DOM element, attach the CSS class to it, and then read and parse the required style property). But, is there a more elegant way to achive it? Is it a bug in the JSF library (I'm using Mojarra 2.0.3, with Jboss 6.1), or there is a reason for that behavior?

Please mind that the code above is part of a tag library, so workarounds such as [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file) can't be used.

---

**Edit** - Seems that the CSS workaround is not feasible, since I can't see a way to get CSS attribute from a CSS file. So any (working) workaround would be gladly accepted as well.

Comment: I just recently found out, to my surprise, that EL is evaluated in CSS. The Mojarra implementation uses a ResourceHelper that is capable of resolving EL Expressions within resources requested by a Faces Resource Request. Thats why I wonder that EL is not evaluated in JS files as it is the same type of request. Would be great if anyone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC has answered a similar question in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file). Though the first solution is the easiest to implement, I would recommend you to go with the third, which in my opinion, is the correct way.