# How to use EL in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, el

i have a **javascript** function that was defined in the **xhtml page**, and i was able to use EL inside it, now when i moved the function to an external JS file, i am not able to use EL like:

```
#{request.contextPath}

#{myBackingBean.myProperty}
```

so, i was wondering how to accomplish something like that in external JS?

Comment: It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just declare some input parameters for the external java script 's function .When calling the external  java script 's function in JSF , you can use the EL expression to access the values from the beans and pass them to the external java script 's function.

Something like this:

```
function someExternalJsFunction(var1,var2,...,varX)
{

}
```

Then in the JSF:

```
<h:commandLink action="....."  
onclick="someExternalJsFunction(#{request.contextPath},#{myBackingBean.myProperty},....)"/>
```

Comment: i used this solution and it sounds good, but BTW the el inside the javascript call needs to be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task. But you can leverage [HTML5 `data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attributes and put your EL expressions in there and read them from JavaScript later.