# How to do the console.log for EL expression in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, el

How to do the console.log for EL expression in JS file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.js-bbCheckbox').click(function(event) {
        var bbck = '${tagOne}';
        console.log (bbck);
        console.log (${tagTwo});
});
```

Comment: Please get your terms right. The `${foo}` is not a "JSTL tag". It's an "EL expression". I edited the question accordingly. In the meanwhile, please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info to learn what JSTL really is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start, you need to understand that JSP (and JSTL and EL) basically **produces** HTML (and CSS and JS) code. It doesn't run in sync with JavaScript code. If you rightclick the JSP page in webbrowser and do *View Source* then you'll see it.

I think that your concrete problem is caused because the `${tagTwo}` returns a plain vanilla string which is in turn by JS been interpreted as a variable name, because it isn't been enclosed in quotes.

You need to let JSP print a fullworthy JS string instead of a variable name.

```
console.log('${tagTwo}');
```

Comment: By doing this I am just getting it print, I would like to get the value of that tag.

Comment: Apparently that part of JS code is not been enclosed in a `.jsp` file, but in a plain `.js` file which is imported by `<script src="some.js"></script>`. Is this true? The EL expressions will obviously only work inside a JSP file as that's been parsed by `JspServlet`. E.g. `<script>console.log('${tagTwo}');</script>`.

Comment: Thats what I was trying to find out that is it possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file/2547908#2547908

Answer (score 0):

@Shoaib Ud-Din, if you don't mind a little inline code, this should work with any included .js file that is loaded after this in the DOM:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="tagOne" value="Hello World" scope="session" />
<script>
    var bbck = "<c:out value="${tagOne}" />";
    console.info("<c:out value="${tagOne}" />");
</script>
```