# Jsp expression language not evaluated in .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, java-ee-6

I am making a Java EE 6 application and using Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

I wan't to use EL inside a jquery script, stored in a sepparate .js file but I can't get it to work. This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#classLabel").change(function(){
        var unsetList = ${classyJson};
        var chosen = $("select#classLabel").val();
      $("select#classSubLabel").val(chosen);
    });    
});
```

And I get the following error message from netbeans:

"subLabelSet.js: Expected ; but found { 
Expected semicolon ; after 'classy'.
The global variable 'classy' is not declared."

The same script works fine if I put it directly in the .jsp file like this:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Titly</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/generateSavedSearchTable.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/subLabelSet.js" ></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select#classLabel").change(function(){
                    var unsetList = ${classyJson};
                    var chosen = $("select#classLabel").val();
                  $("select#classSubLabel").val(chosen);
                });    
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

This reminded me of a problem I had before where I couldn't get the EL to evaluate inside files ending in '.jspf'. This I fixed by adding:

```
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>Used to enable interpretation of EL in jspf files</description>
        <display-name>jspf</display-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jspf/*</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
```

in the web.xml file. But when I try to do the same for .js files:

```
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>Used to enable interpretation of EL in javascript files</description>
        <display-name>javascript</display-name>
        <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
```

I does not work and I get the following error:

---

SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\S1\Documents\netbeansprojects\UI\build\web\js\generateSavedSearchTable.js" not found

SEVERE: Error compiling file: C:\S1\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\UI\org\apache\jsp\js\jquery_002d1_10_2_js.java

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
code too large for try statement
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
code too large for try statement
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
code too large
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

---

Any ideas on what is going wrong and if/how I can fix it?

Comment: This looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814