# Disable days when change months

Tags: primefaces, calendar

I am using a function to disable all days excepts mondays or enable the next working day to the holiday monday. I run the function before show the calendar and it works perfectly but I need to run the function again when the user change the current month in the calendar.

**This is the calendar:**

```
<p:calendar beforeShowDay="disableDays" navigator="true" readonlyInput="true" showOn="button" value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" timeZone="#{timeZone}" />
</p:calendar>
```

**And the function:**

```
function disableDays(date) {
    var datesToDisable = [ "8-1-2015", "8-2-2015", "8-4-2015", "8-5-2015", "8-6-2015", "8-7-2015", "8-8-2015", "8-9-2015", "8-11-2015", "8-12-2015", "8-13-2015", "8-14-2015", "8-15-2015", "8-16-2015", "8-17-2015", "8-19-2015", "8-20-2015", "8-21-2015", "8-22-2015", "8-23-2015", "8-25-2015", "8-26-2015", "8-27-2015", "8-28-2015", "8-29-2015", "8-30-2015" ];
    var month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate(), annio = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < datesToDisable.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray((month + 1) + '-' + day + '-' + annio, datesToDisable) != -1) {
            return [ false ];
        }
    }
    return [ true ];
}
```

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Put the disableDays javascript function within a block that you update via ajax when a month change event happens on the Calendar. Then use EL within the javascript function that puts the new days to disable in there. See point 1 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file

Comment: what is the change month event?

Comment: Sorry it is called the viewChange event what it is can be read in the PF docs

Comment: It doesn't appear in the pdf docs, thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, (and please take a little offence) then do not know how to use ctrl-f. It is on page 55 of the 5.2 docs... wow...

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don't find how to use it and I don't find an example nowhere

Comment: It is to be used as any other event that you can use with ajax. I hope that much is clear. And how to use p:ajax   can be found on > 1.000 sites on the internet.

Comment: Excuse me, because my native language is spanish sometimes is hard to me to explain what is my problem. I know how to use ajax  calls in primefaces. The problem is disabling the days in the calendar for other monts when the user change the date

Comment: English not being your native language is not really a problem I think, since it is not to bad. But if you doubt that, use Google translate. Now on topic: You know how to disable dates, you know how to use ajax, I gave a link to a page where you can see how to use EL in javascript, and also told that you should put the disableDays function in a block that you update via Ajax. You should be able to combine that, or at least give it a try and post where you get so we can comment on that. That is what you don't do and that has nothing to do with English not being your native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a summary in partly pseudo code when all the comments on the question would be interpreted and worked with. It could contain typos, wrong classes but the intention is what counts now. Maybe I'll improve it later

**xhtml:**

```
<p:calendar...>
    <p:ajax event="viewChange" listener="#{bean.myViewAction}" update="scriptPanel" />
</p:calendar>

<h:panelGroup id="scriptPanel">
    <script>
        function disableDays(date) {
            var datesToDisable = #{bean.disableDates};
            var month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate(), annio = date.getFullYear();
            for (i = 0; i < datesToDisable.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray((month + 1) + '-' + day + '-' + annio, datesToDisable) != -1) {
                    return [ false ];
                }
            }
            return [ true ];
        }
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Bean:**

```
public void viewChange(DateViewChangeEvent e) { 
    // Get relvant info from event
    // determine new disableDates and set those in the correct formatted string
}

public void getDisableDates() {
    return disableDates;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the answer (I'll 'accept' the changes) to what you realy have and create a new question

Comment: :-D I meant you to improve the answer so it contains more real code. But this is fine to. Next time,  you should experiment more based on comments. This is all not to difficult

Comment: You can see the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998536/disable-days-in-the-other-calendar-when-month-is-changed If you can help me