# ${findState} value is not getting if script file placed outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, liferay-6.2

I have created a liferay portlet with ajax feature, The application is working fine but the issue is that say when I put the ajax script within the jsp page like as shown below I will be able to pass the ${findState} url but If I include the javascipt outside within a js file and tries to trigger the ajax I am not getting the value of ${findState} and is showing error.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:resourceURL id="findState" var="findState" ></portlet:resourceURL>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#country" ).change(function() {
      $.ajax({
            url: "${findState}" ,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype:'json',
            data: { 
                    countryName: $("#country").val() 
              },
                success: function(data){
                var content= JSON.parse(data);
                $('#state').html('');// to clear the previous option
                $.each(content, function(i, state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>').text(state.name).attr('value', state.stateId));
                });
            }
        });
  }); 
});
</script>

<b>Change the Country State Change By Ajax</b> <br><br>
Country:
<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="select">Select Country</option>
<option value="india">India</option>
<option value="usa">USA</option>
</select>

<br><br>
State:
<select id="state" name="state">
</select>
```

Can anyo please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${findState} is an expression language variable that is being processed on the server by the JSP engine. So at runtime, in the browser, the `url: "${findState}"` property is in fact a `url: "someUrlString"`.
When you move the Javascript portion of the code in a separate js file, that file will no longer be processed by the server (the JSP engine).

My suggestion would be to wrap the ajax call in a function in a separate js file (named `yourJavascriptFile.js`, for example) containing the following:

```
var callAjax = function(ajaxUrl) {
      $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl ,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype:'json',
            data: { 
                    countryName: $("#country").val() 
              },
                success: function(data){
                var content= JSON.parse(data);
                $('#state').html('');// to clear the previous option
                $.each(content, function(i, state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>').text(state.name).attr('value', state.stateId));
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Then your JSP should have the following:

```
<script src="yourJavascriptFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#country" ).change(function() {
      callAjax("${findState}");
  }); 
});
</script>
```

In other words, you're trying to mix expression language variables into external JS files that will not be executed by your server engine. Please see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547814/mixing-jsf-el-in-a-javascript-file) for other solutions to this kind of problem.